# htmlentities not giving wanted result

Tags: php, special-characters, htmlspecialchars

I have the following function below how ever the result is still giving me `string(13) "hell'o"o"`
 and not the special chars

**Function:**

```
private function makeHTMLSpecial($input)
        {
            return htmlentities(trim($input), ENT_QUOTES);
        }
```

**Code:**

```
$new_descriptionCheck = $this->input->post('desc');

$new_description      = $this->makeHTMLSpecial($new_descriptionCheck);
```

Comment: it will be useful if you add more code

Comment: Curious how `hell'o"o` has 8 symbols but it says its 13 in length. Perhaps it is doing just what its supposed to, but you are watching the output in a browser and not seeing that.

Comment: `string(13)` -- It is giving ***exactly*** the wanted result.

Comment: Agreed, the string length of 13 is correct after run through `htmlspecialchars()` because `&quot;` takes up 6 characters (see my update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your bracketing correct?

```
private function makeHTMLSpecial($input)
{
    return htmlentities(trim($input), ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

---

Testing string length...

```
$string = "hell'o\"o";
var_dump($string); // string 'hell'o"o' (length=8)
var_dump(htmlspecialchars($string)); // string 'hell'o&quot;o' (length=13)
```

Comment: Thanks,  it still didnt fix the issue - I have updated the code sadly there is not that much code to go on